# How to mutate a mean of certain rows in a data frame

Tags: r, mean, dplyr

I would like to create a new column which equals to the mean of several variables (columns) in my data frame. However, I'm afraid I can't use 'rowMeans' because I don't want to average all variables. Moreover, I'm hesitate to manually type all the variable names (which are many). For example:

```
my_data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), c = c(10,10,10), d = c(13,24,81),
                      e = c(10, 8, 6), hello = c(1,-1,1), bye = c(1,5,5))
```

I want to mutate a row called avg which is the average of variables a, b, c, d, and e only. Because in my dataset, the variables names are long (and complex), and there are more than 10 variables, I prefer not to type them out one by one. So I guess I might need to use dplyr package and the mutate function?? Could you please suggest a clever way for me to do that?

The below content is added after your kind comments and answers suggest. Thank you all again:

Actually, the column names that I needed are Mcheck5_1_1, Mcheck5_2_1, ..., Mcheck5_8_1 (so there are 8 in total).However, I tried 
`my_data$avg = rowMeans(select(my_data, Mcheck5_1_1:Mcheck5_8_1), na.rm = TRUE)`
but an error was thrown to me:

```
Error in select(my_data, Mcheck5_1_1:Mcheck5_8_1) : 
unused argument (Mcheck5_1_1:Mcheck5_8_1)
```

Right now I solved the problem by using the following code:

```
`idx = grep("Mcheck5_1_1", names(my_data))
my_data$avg = rowMeans(my_data[, idx:idx+7], na.rm = TRUE)`
```

But is there a more elegant way to do it? Or why couldn't I use `select()`? Thanks!

Comment: You'll at least need some kind of rule to get the variables you need.

Comment: *dplyr* isn't necessarily needed, just `my_data$rowmn <- rowMeans(my_data[,1:5])` will be sufficient; or in *dplyr*: `my_data %>% mutate(rowmn = rowMeans(.[1:5]))`

Comment: You provide a data.frame example. Could you use it to provide an expected output? I'm confused as to what you want exactly.

Comment: Dear Jaap, Thank you very much for your reply. The variable names are Mcheck5_1_1 to Mcheck5_8_1. Yes, I could index the variable using grep function, and I know exactly how many variables that I need to aggregate. However, I was think about sth like Mcheck5_1_1: Mcheck5_8_1. Is it possible to do it? Thank you very much!

Comment: What sets the variables you want to include apart from those you want to exclude? column names? column class? Column position? something else? Without this information it's not possible to answer your question. Once you know this, it should be relatively easy to achieve what you want to do with either subsetting or the dplyr::select_helpers

Comment: I added my error, thank you for your advice NiclasRudolfson

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
my_data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), c = c(10,10,10), d = c(13,24,81),
                      e = c(10, 8, 6), hello = c(1,-1,1), bye = c(1,5,5))

several_variables <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e') #3 or `letters[1:5]`
my_data$avg <- rowMeans(my_data[,several_variables])
my_data
#>   a b  c  d  e hello bye  avg
#> 1 1 4 10 13 10     1   1  7.6
#> 2 2 5 10 24  8    -1   5  9.8
#> 3 3 6 10 81  6     1   5 21.2
```

Obviously, if the variables is at some fixed position, and you know they will stay there, you could use the numbered indexing as [suggested by Jaap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629767/how-to-mutate-a-mean-of-certain-rows-in-a-data-frame/46631012#comment80209332_46629767),

```
my_data$avg <- rowMeans(my_data[,1:5])
```